# OS X secondary monitor resolution off a MacBook Pro: how do I increase it?

Tags: macos, display, resolution

I have a MacBook Pro, and have tried to connect both a Benq g900 and Samsung SyncMaster to it.

They work, but in both cases the Mac drops down to 640x800 res, and won't increase it.

I gather this is because I'm missing a driver.  I could only find a Benq driver -- Windows only, and didn't find anything for the SyncMaster.

How can I increase the resolution, and - if I need a driver - where's a non-dubious site where I can find it for OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need a driver for an external display.  Just check the System Preferences for Display settings and click `Detect Displays` to get the OS to refresh its list of available resolutions.  Also, If you choose to mirror the primary display then the resolutions listed will only be the ones common to both monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Disable mirroring of your monitors in the *Displays* section of *System Preferences*. When mirroring is turned on you will only see resolutions that both monitors support. With mirroring turned off you can select the resolution of each monitor.